# Google+ get all companies in a city

Tags: api, google-plus

I'm doing some working with Google+ and I'm wondering if it's possible to get all businesses within a certain city, or near a postal code.

By a business, I mean a g+ page like this:
https://plus.google.com/104369663349033651320/

I cant seem to find any appropriate API for this and their site structure doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I suspect that Google would consider that information, when gathered together, sufficiently valuable that they aren't going to make it easy to retrieve without paying for it.

Comment: Seeing as there is a public, free-to-use API for searching posts, I don't understand why one for searching businesses would not be.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) for searching places near a location. The Nearby Search requires a lat,long pair but should be able to get that via the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).